# Is there a way to view a UIViewController behind another UIViewController without messing with the AppDelegate window?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, uiwindow, rootviewcontroller

There is a library I really enjoy that you could find here (https://github.com/pixyzehn/MediumMenu).

Essentially it does the following:

[image: MediumMenu Demo]

The menu in the back is actually a UIViewController. If we delve into the source code, we'll find the following very important code:

```
public init(items: [MediumMenuItem], forViewController: UIViewController) {
    self.init()
    self.items = items
    height = screenHeight - 80 // auto-calculate initial height based on screen size
    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: height)
    contentController = forViewController
    menuContentTableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
    menuContentTableView?.delegate = self
    menuContentTableView?.dataSource = self
    menuContentTableView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    menuContentTableView?.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    menuContentTableView?.backgroundColor = menuBackgroundColor
    addSubview(menuContentTableView!)

    if panGestureEnable {
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MediumMenu.didPan(_:)))
        contentController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
    }

    let menuController = UIViewController()
    menuController.view = self

   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = contentController
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.insertSubview(menuController.view, atIndex: 0)
}
```

The first few lines aren't really important, but the very last lines (the ones dealing with the `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??` are the key to this library working, but they also limit the library.

According to those lines, we're making the UIViewController that we want the menu for to be the `rootViewController` and then we add the menu view to the window at the 0 index (I'm guessing this is what puts it in the back, behind the `contentController`).

**The problem with the library:**

The library only works if you want the menu on the initial view controller. In a sense, only if the contentController is already the rootViewController. It'll actually function for me in my app, but I can't segue back to my original UIViewController because it isn't in the hierarchy anymore.

I have a scenario where I have a Login View Controller, and when you successfully login, I segue you to my UINavigationController on which I want the menu. The first clear sign of an issue is that I get the complaint **"Warning: Attempt to present UINavigationController on LoginViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"** Obviously, it isn't in the window hierarchy because I'm reassigning the rootViewController.

I don't know how to fix this. Is there a way to have this functionality work when the UIViewController I want the menu on isn't the initial view controller?

Comment: Is your initial `UIViewController` is `UINavigationController` ?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is: **Yes**.

This can be implemented with by assigning a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` to the `ViewController` containing the `list-menu` and implementing the `interactionControllerForPresentation()` and `interactionControllerForDismissal()` methods. You don't have to touch the `UIWindow` (*directly*).

You could just change this part about the existing `library`, but from the looks of it it's just a `TableView` with a fancy transition. You could easily implement this yourself.

Check out Apple's [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate) on interactive transitions and [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions) by Ray Wenderlich for a hands on example.

Answer (score 2):

So it is clear your scenario is:

1. `rootViewController` = a `UINavigationController`
2. the `rootViewController` of `UINavigationController` is the LoginController
3. When someone login succeed, the `navigationController` push(or segue) to a menuController

or

1. `rootViewController` is the LoginController
2. When someone login succeed, it will present the menuController

So the key point is to get a menuController and not set it to the `rootViewController` of the app.

Here is the code which i made some change to fit your requirement.
https://github.com/Moonsownner/MediumMenu-master

**What did i do:**

1. `MediumMenu` actually is a `UIView`, we have to create a controller to contain it so that to make the transition. So i make a new class named `MediumMenuController`. And you can see i move function `showMenu` into `MediumMenuController`. So if someone want to show the menu manually, the target must be a MediumMenuController not the previous `NavigationController`. And the `MediumMenuController` will contain your business controller which you send in into the init function of `MediumMenuController`.

> ```
> class MediumMenuController: UIViewController {
>
>     let menuView: MediumMenu
>     let child: UIViewController
>
>     init(items: [MediumMenuItem], childController: UIViewController){
>         self.menuView = MediumMenu(items: items, forViewController: childController)
>         self.child = childController
>         super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
>     }
>
>     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
>         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
>     }
>
>     override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>
>         view.addSubview(menuView)
>         addChildViewController(child)
>         self.view.addSubview(child.view)
>         child.view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
>         child.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
>
>     }
>
>     func showMenu() {
>         menuView.show()
>     }
>
> }
> ```

2. I delete the code in `MediumMenu`.

> let menuController = UIViewController(); menuController.view = self
>   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController
>   = contentController UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.insertSubview(menuController.view,
>   atIndex: 0)

and create a new controller named `MediumMenuController` to add the `MediumMenu` and the other controllers views to it.

Maybe it is not clear by saying above. The code can show you the detail. Good luck.

Comment: Your answer should show the key code additions, not deletions alone, because eventually yhat link will break and this answer will be meaningless

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by following steps.

(i)  Make `LoginViewController` as your `rootViewController`.

(ii) When user signs in successfully, redirect user to Home Screen. That is your first screen that you want to show after successfully logged in.

(iii) You can make a parent class of `UIViewControllers` where you want to show the menu.

(iv) After that, when you initialize any `UIViewController`, parent class will call `public init(items: [MediumMenuItem], forViewController: UIViewController)` method and in that you can replace last two lines with below code.
`self.view.insertSubview(menuController.view, atIndex: 0)`

(v) On tapping sign out button, you can simply dismiss presented view controller, so `LoginViewController` will always be there.

Hope this helps!